# What is the Big-Oh complexity of this generic tree method?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures, big-o

I was asked to implement a method that removes from a (non binary, n-ary) tree nodes that have a height of a given K value, and only one child. This is my implementation:

This is the tree node's height function, even though I know it's O(n), I don't quite get why.

```
private int height(Position<E> pos) throws InvalidPositionException { // O(n)
        //Inicia un valor antes del try para evitar que no se inicie.
        TNode<E> nodo = null;
        int maxHeight = 0; 
        try {
            nodo = checkPosition(pos);          //Casteo
            } catch (InvalidPositionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (isExternal(nodo)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            for (TNode<E> aux : nodo.getChildren()) {
                int auxHeight = height(aux);
                if (auxHeight > maxHeight) {
                    maxHeight = auxHeight;
                }
            }
            return 1+maxHeight;
        }   
    }
```

```
private TNode<E> checkPosition(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException{
        if (p==null) throw new InvalidPositionException("Posición Inválida");
        try{
            return (TNode<E>) p; //Intenta castear
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new InvalidPositionException("Posición Inválida.");
        }
    }
```

And this is the complex function I need the Big-O of:

```
public void removerNodos(int K) throws InvalidPositionException {
        for (Position<E> pos : positions()) {
            TNode<E> nodo = checkPosition(pos);
            if ((height(nodo) == K) && nodo.getChildren().size()==1) {

                //Si el nodo que cumple las caracteristicas es la raiz, lo eliminamos.
                if (isRoot(nodo)) {
                    try {
                        root.setElement(null);
                        root.setChildren(null);
                        root = root.getChildren().first().element();
                        root.setParent(null);

                    } catch (EmptyListException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            //Caso contrario: ASUMO PASAJE DE HIJO AL PADRE.
            else {      
                try {
                        TNode<E> hijo = nodo.getChildren().first().element();
                        TNode<E> padre = nodo.getParent();
                        hijo.setParent(padre);
                        padre.getChildren().addLast(hijo);
                        E value  = nodo.element();

                        //Busca en la lista de posiciones de nodos del padre el elemento a
                        //eliminar, y lo quita. Operación de lista.
                        for (TDALista.Position<TNode<E>> aux : padre.getChildren().positions()) {
                            if (aux.element() == nodo) padre.getChildren().remove(aux);
                        }
                        nodo.setElement(null);
                        nodo.setChildren(null);
                        nodo.setParent(null);
                        size--; 
                        //Reducimos el tamaño del arbol.
                        //System.out.println("Se eliminó el nodo "+value+".");

                    } catch (EmptyListException | TDALista.InvalidPositionException e) {
                            System.out.println("Lista de nodos vacia, o posición inválida");
                    }       
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

If you need to understand the variable names just comment and I can translate them.

Comment: Hint: If there are n nodes in the tree, how many times do you traverse each node in worst case? Do you traverse different nodes different number of times?

Comment: That's my problem. I believe traversing in worst case for the height is the best case for the "for" loop that looks for brothers and vice versa. If a linear tree is generated, the worst case is actually not so bad. Is there something I'm missing here? It would not make any sense taking always the worst case when it cannot happen.

Comment: I think the worst case would be N (because of the main for loop) * N (Worst case for each node height that is irrealistic that each will have N order) * N (Worst case, every node is a brother in height 1 (which is mutually exclusive with the previous assumption)

Comment: Thinking in depth, is it possible the Big Oh of this particular method is O(N * (M+N)), being M the number of nodes under a given node's level, and N the number of the greatest quantity of brother nodes there is in the tree? @GyaptiJain

Comment: You can simplify it and call N(N * N).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `height` function has a time complexity of *O(n)* because it will only execute once per node (passed as argument) -- the recursive calls never happen twice for the same node.

The main function `removerNodos` runs with a time complexity that depends on the actual node arity and height of the tree. The worst case is *O(n²)*. For instance, the worst case occurs in a tree where each node has one child, except for one: the only leaf -- a chain. The `height` function is called for each node, and so the total number of node-visits for this particular tree-format is *1+2+3+...+n = O(n²)*.

The manipulation to delete a single node is *O(1)* when we consider the arity a constant, so that doesn't influence the overall time complexity.

### Some issues in the code

Not your question, but there are some shortcomings:

- The `size` is not decremented in the `if` case, i.e. when the root is deleted.
- When you call `.setChildren(null)`, any subsequent call of `.getChildren()` will return an empty list and so `.first()` will not return a child node, as the children were just detached and would not be retrieved any more. So better change the following:

  ```
      root.setChildren(null);
      root = root.getChildren().first().element();
  ```

  to:

  ```
      TNode<E> hijo = root.getChildren().first().element();
      root.setChildren(null);
      root = hijo;
  ```

### Improvements

The code is not very efficient. You would get a better time complexity when you would not call `height` for each node, but would actually perform a depth first search (like in the `height` function) and would merge the calculation of the height with the deletion logic. In other words, use the `height` function as the *main* function; add the *k* parameter to it, and implement the deletion logic inside of it.

This way you don't perform a repeated DFS involving some of the *same* nodes (as you have now), and you also don't need to look for the index in the parent's children to find the current node, as with the backtracking in the DFS you'll know the exact index where you were recurring into that node.

If you implement it that way, it will run in *O(n)*.